# Android: Kotlin - Retrofit2 - Moshi | working with complex json

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, moshi

I'm trying to get a list of games using this API request.
https://steamspy.com/api.php?request=top100forever

However I believe that my issue is that all games are inside another thing with just the appid.
This is what the response looks like

```
{
  "10": {
    "appid": 10,
    "name": "Counter-Strike",
    "developer": "Valve",
    "publisher": "Valve",
    "score_rank": "",
    "positive": 143404,
    "negative": 3739,
    "userscore": 0,
    "owners": "20,000,000 .. 50,000,000",
    "average_forever": 9671,
    "average_2weeks": 815,
    "median_forever": 287,
    "median_2weeks": 925,
    "price": "99",
    "initialprice": "999",
    "discount": "90"
  },
  "30": {
    "appid": 30,
    "name": "Day of Defeat",
    "developer": "Valve",
    "publisher": "Valve",
    "score_rank": "",
    "positive": 3885,
    "negative": 463,
    "userscore": 0,
    "owners": "5,000,000 .. 10,000,000",
    "average_forever": 259,
    "average_2weeks": 0,
    "median_forever": 33,
    "median_2weeks": 0,
    "price": "49",
    "initialprice": "499",
    "discount": "90"
  },
  ....
}
```

My apiService:

```
private const val BASE_URL_GAMES = "https://steamspy.com/"

private val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    //.add(ResponseGetGamesAdapter())
    .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
    .build()

//OkhttpClient for building http request url
private val tmdbClient = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
    .build()

private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .client(tmdbClient)
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
    .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL_GAMES)
    .build()


interface GameApiService{
    @GET("api.php?request=top100forever")
    fun getTop100(): Deferred<List<Game>>

}



object GameApi {
    val retrofitService: GameApiService by lazy {
        retrofit.create(GameApiService::class.java)
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
enum class GameApiStatus { LOADING, ERROR, DONE }

class GameOverviewViewModel : ViewModel() {
    // TODO: Implement the
    private val _response = MutableLiveData<String>()
    private val _status = MutableLiveData<GameApiStatus>()

    //private var gameRepository: GameRepository = GameRepository()

    // The external immutable LiveData for the response String
    val response: LiveData<GameApiStatus>
        get() = _status

    private val _properties = MutableLiveData<List<Game>>()
    val properties: LiveData<List<Game>>
        get() = _properties

    // Create a Coroutine scope using a job to be able to cancel when needed
    private var viewModelJob = Job()

    // the Coroutine runs using the Main (UI) dispatcher
    private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(viewModelJob + Dispatchers.Main )

    init {
        getTop100()
    }

    private fun getTop100() {
        coroutineScope.launch {
            // Get the Deferred object for our Retrofit request
            var getPropertiesDeferred = GameApi.retrofitService.getTop100()
            try {
                // Await the completion of our Retrofit request
                var listResult = getPropertiesDeferred.await()
                _status.value = GameApiStatus.DONE
                _properties.value = listResult
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                val error = e.message
                _status.value = GameApiStatus.ERROR
                _properties.value = ArrayList()
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * When the [ViewModel] is finished, we cancel our coroutine [viewModelJob], which tells the
     * Retrofit service to stop.
     */
    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        viewModelJob.cancel()
    }
}
```

Game model

```
data class Game(
    //var id:Int,
    @field:Json(name = "appid")
    var appid:Int,
    @field:Json(name = "name")
    var name:String
    //var desc:String
)
```

At this point I've been struggling so long I've probably broken more stuff on the way lol
I assume I need some kind of adapter, but I'm absolutely clueless.
Was trying to stick as close as possible to how it's done in our course, but at this point I'll take any working way :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the update as below: 
Update the service

```
interface GameApiService{
    @GET("api.php?request=top100forever")
    fun getTop100(): Deferred<Map<String,Game>>
}
```

Then you will get the result of map from the API.

Comment: Well that was a simple fix that worked out for me thanks :D You don't happen to have an equally great idea for this one? Need some of the stuff that's in data, but this one also has a "success" bool in it  https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=218620

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem is here:

```
interface GameApiService{
@GET("api.php?request=top100forever")
fun getTop100(): Deferred<List<Game>>
}
```

You're saying in your code that you'll get a `List` of a `Game` object, but your api is not giving you that.

This is the response from your api:

```
{
  "10": {
    "appid": 10,
    ...
    },
  "30": {
    "appid": 30,
    ...
    }
}
```

What your API is returning in this example is an object `10`, which inside contains lots of other data, and an object `30`, which contains lots of other data.
Seems like `10` and `30` contain the same fields, so that can help down the road.

This means you can create a new data class, which can be called `GameServiceResponse`.

```
data class GameServiceResponse(
    @Json(name = "10") val 10: Game,
    @Json(name = "30") val 30: Game
)
```

And then you change your `GameApiService` to accept this response. However, you were never receiving a `List` in the first place, so that has to go.

```
interface GameApiService{
@GET("api.php?request=top100forever")
fun getTop100(): Deferred<GameServiceResponse>
}
```

Finally, when you consume this, you're gonna get something like `getPropertiesDeferred.10.appid`

One more thing: since you're using moshi, I believe you still need to tell the api class that you're deserializing with moshi (may not be needed if your adapter is doing this part):

```
interface GameApiService{

@MoshiDeserialization
@GET("api.php?request=top100forever")
fun getTop100(): Deferred<GameServiceResponse>
}
```

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks, that is a help already :D not sure if it's feasible to do for 100 games though. Is there no way to make this work without having to manually define them all?

Comment: you can define it as a generic type, and make the `GameServiceResponse` take a generic type instead